# Need help understanding answer calculating the expected value?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

[image]

In the following solution, I am not sure how $f_x(x)$ got the value $\frac{1}{2\pi}$.

I'm familiar with the expected value for continuous variables calculation.

Answer (score 1):

$f_{\mathbf x}(x)$ is the density of $x$, which in the case of a continuous uniform distribution in the interval $(a,b]$ is $f_{\mathbf x}(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}$ for all $x \in (a,b]$, 0 elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you! Is a uniform distribution always specified by the (] brackets?

Comment: A continuous univariate uniform distribution, yes. Note that you can define a uniform distribution on any set, although the standard is as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)